# Dynamically creating connection string EF6.0 causes problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I have the following code somewhere in the application. the code goes like this:

```
    Hyperion.Data.MCQEntities _model = null;
    const string K_MODEL = @"res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;";

    public Engine(string cnnstr)
    {
       //string connection =(new ConnectionStringBuilder(cnnstr)).ToString();
        string connectionString = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Metadata = K_MODEL, //"res://*",
            Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
            ProviderConnectionString = cnnstr,
        }.ConnectionString;

        _model = new Data.MCQEntities(connectionString);
        _model.Connection.Open(); 
    }
```

the problem I do not understand is that when I use `Metadata = "res://*"` it works but when I use `Metadata=K_MODEL` it does not work at all. what could be the issue?

Comment: Have you double-checked that your `K_MODEL` value is correct? My connection string Metadata appear to follow this pattern: `res://*/Entity.{0}.csdl|res://*/Entity.{0}.ssdl|res://*/Entity.{0}.msl`

Comment: checked many times. my work is not stuck and I'm already using the other form that works. I simply want to know why it is behaving like this? deleting model and recreating, as some suggested, is not a solution. the resources are embedded, if they were not then res://* would never work. and I have confirmed the model file name and loc also. what is going on behind the scenes?

Comment: I don't know how all this works behind the scenes. Does it work if you use that same connection string in a config file, rather than injecting it? You might want to double-check that your constructor hasn't been changed to do some black magic.

Answer (score 0):

`res//*` tells EF that metadata is embedded in the assembly as a resource. If you skip it EF is looking for file on the disk. The default build action for edmx is to embed artifacts in the assembly so if you have not changed this files are not on disk and EF cannot find them.